# How to handle NotFoundHttpException in Pimcore(Symfony) routing.yml?

Tags: php, symfony, exception, routes, pimcore

I am currently working on a Pimcore project based on symfony.Here I've create a bundle where all my API's are stored and they are working fine am able to return json response successfully.

I have configured settings as shown in image below in routing.yml

[image]

This defaults: _format: json is handling all Pimcore(Symfony) errors and returning them in JSON format properly. But when there is a **NotFoundHttpException** it is returning **HTML** as response.

Is there any ay that i can get NotFoundHttpException also in JSON format.

Here the issue is that I don't want to add it on the listener level because then it is applied to pimcore's UI part also Which i don't want.

If there is any solution please suggest.

Also is there any way t customize the JSON data in routing.yml also suggest only for Exceptions.

Thank You.